# L_ERRORCODE0 => 11813 - Invalid callback URL. Paypal reccuring payments working on sandbox test account but not in live

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I Have problem with paypal API and reccuring payments. I have already working sandbox test account:

```
define('API_USERNAME', 'API-USERNAME');
define('API_PASSWORD', 'API-PASSWORD');
define('API_SIGNATURE', 'API-SIGNATURE');
define('API_ENDPOINT', 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
define('PAYPAL_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=');
define('PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT', 'sandbox');
```

But when I try to add my live credentials I can see only error after click to checkout:

```
define('API_USERNAME', 'API-Username');
define('API_PASSWORD', 'API-PASS');
define('API_SIGNATURE', 'API-Signature');
define('API_ENDPOINT', 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
define('PAYPAL_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=');
define('PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT', 'live');
```

NoW when I click to checkout, website show me error:

```
SetExpressCheckout failed: Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d02%2d01T11%3a53%3a32Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4caf5dc7552f2
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 98%2e0
    [BUILD] => 9285531
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11813
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Callback%20URL%20is%20wrong%20type%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Callback%20URL%20is%20wrong%20type%3b%20you%20must%20use%20the%20HTTPS%2e
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

I will be very happy for any help!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *callback* URL needs to be HTTPS. That probably refers to the notify_url posted in the form or defined at Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `PAYPAL_URL` is wrong. You need to re-check it. I think it should be as below.

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=
```

**UPDATE**

This happens if you have your Express option: `Transfer Shipping Options = Yes` but do not have an HTTPS address for your website. It passes the shipping options over to PayPal so customers can change the shipping of their order while on PayPal’s website. This transfer of information is, quite rightly, only done using HTTPS.

If you set the option to no then your customers are redirected back to your website to select the shipping making the checkout process a bit less express.

You can either get an `SSL certificate` so PayPal uses HTTPS or set the `Transfer shipping option to No`.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for opinion I have already change URL and edited code. I have still error...

Comment: I have still problem with that do you have any Idea? Thanks a lot lot lot!

Comment: which programming language you are using?

Comment: PHP language, why? what do you think ? Do I need to have SSL ? What do you think ?

Comment: OK, thanks. I don't think you also need SSL because i did this think before in one of my projects.(I followed this nice example to configure things https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example/blob/master/paypalfunctions.php , you can also check if you like) You just need is proper credentials, callbacks and parameter you post to PayPal. Can you post final url here that you post on PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

The Callback URL is used so that you can build a web service that PayPal's review page will "call back" to in order to pull real-time shipping and sales calculations into their review page so users can finalize payment there.

In your SetExpressCheckout request there are parameters for callback that you must have set incorrectly.  Since you're unsure what it is, I would assume you're not actually trying to use it, so you should probably just remove them entirely.